# Change existing Azure Function's hosting OS from Windows to Linux

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Currently we have a **Function App** in **Azure** which is hosted in Windows. Initially once you create, you need to choose the hosting environment as below:

[image: azure-function-hosting]

***Question:***

Is there any chance to change the underlying hosting environment for already created **Azure Functions**? I did not find anything related to that even in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

Appreciate the clarification.

Comment: No, this is not a setting you can change once it has been set. Out of curiosity, are you hosting your function on the Consumption Plan or App Service Plan?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Change existing Azure Function's hosting OS from Windows to Linux

In short, it's impossible.

Because of the potential of breaking changes, you can only **set the Operating System when you create function**.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that make sense. Could you please add the documentation link as well where you found this statement? Thanks!

Comment: It's a [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=hi59DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=change+azure+function+operating+system+after+created&source=bl&ots=pDJPHW7j-t&sig=ACfU3U21XJ28BOLPNLnYBuP80rQl7BX3og&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV7pqYooXoAhXXbCsKHSpDCD0Q6AEwD3oECAoQAQ#v=snippet&q=%20change%20operating%20system%20after%20created&f=false).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the mentioned book helps.